# How to make Github copilot use single quotes

Tags: github, github-copilot

how to make Github copilot use single quotes instead of double quotes ?
I checked the VSCode settings and can't find it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have the opposite problem. i want double quotes, but mine is using singles.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub copilot adapt to your coding practices,so, just keep writing code and it will start suggesting single quotes after some lines or you can explicitly ask in comment to use single quotes.